# Action creator thunk

Tags: javascript, redux-thunk

На видеокурсе у Юрия Бурда по react-redux увидел странное создание action creator. Как известно он обычно имеет такой вид creator = () => dispatch => ... dispatch(something) , но в видео был показан следующий вариант creator = (getDataFromAPI) => () => dispatch => ... dispatch(something). getDataFromAPI это функция, которая из компонента передается в action creator, так вот, вопрос, почему ее нельзя закинуть в функцию перед dispatch, зачем создавать еще один уровень обертки?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае он и закидывает её перед диспатч. Чтобы потом можно было сначала передать функцию для получения данных и после вызвать её асинхронно, и после в зависимости от результата диспатчить соответствующий синхронный экшон. То есть эту логику можно переиспользовать, передавая разные функции загрузки данных. Написано это в таком виде чтобы всё работало вместе с `thunk`. В уроке №152 на Udemy он неплохо это объясняет.